What is the formula for these initial terms?
$$\frac{2}{3} + \frac{2 * 5}{3 * 5} + \frac{2 * 5 * 8}{3 * 5 * 7}
+\frac{2 * 5 * 8 * 11}{3 * 5 * 7 * 9} ...$$
Trying to use the ratio test on this series, but I can't figure out how to convert it into a workable, exact form. I am looking for a formula for these initial terms. I understand that this is probably a very basic question for the forum, but I would appreciate if anyone has advice.

In the future use "MathJax" for formatting such as $ \frac{2}{3} $ instead of using a photo. Photos of math are frowned upon here due to accessibility issues among other reasons.
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

@qatest fixed. thank you.

@AnneBauval Thank you very much. I appreciate it.

I am not sure I understand your question. If you just want a formula, here it is:$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\prod_{k=0}^n\frac{2+3k}{3+2k}.$$
Note that this series diverges grossly.

I did not even know about this product operator, PI. Thank you for telling me about it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_binary_operation#Notation

@AnneBauval we can also express the denominator using the double factorial

As far as the ratio test goes, you can see that it fails because the numerator is increasing faster than the denominator. For large $n$, the ratio between successive terms is $\tfrac32>1$ so it fails the ratio test and you're done.
You can calculate the ratio between terms more explicitly, if you want:
\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} &= \frac{3(n+1)+2}{2(n+1)+3} = \frac{3n+5}{2n+5} \to \frac32
\end{align}
But your question also asks for the exact form of the $n$-th term, which you don't need to see that it diverges, but just for interest, here is how you work it out. The key is factor out the step (in this case, 3 in the numerator and 2 in the denominator, and there are $n$ factors of each) and recognize the gamma functions:
\begin{align}
a_n &= \frac{(3n+2)(2n-1)\ldots 5 \times 2}{(2n+3)(2n+1)\ldots 5 \times 3}\\
&= \left(\frac32\right)^n\frac{(n+\frac23)(n-\frac13)\ldots\frac53\times\frac23}{(n+\frac32)(n+\frac12)\ldots\frac52\times\frac32}\\
&= \left(\frac32\right)^n\frac{\Gamma(n+\frac53)/\Gamma(\frac23)}{\Gamma(n+\frac52)/\Gamma(\frac32)}.
\end{align}
Edit: you may not be aware of the gamma function, but the only property we're using here is that $\Gamma(n+1)=n\Gamma(n)$, and were using it recursively.
As a check, you can get the ratio of terms:
\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} &= \frac{3\Gamma(n+1+\frac53)\Gamma(n+\frac52)}{2\Gamma(n+1+\frac52)\Gamma(n+\frac53)}\\
&=\frac{3(n+\frac53)}{2(n+\frac52)}\\ &= \frac{3n+5}{2n+5}
\end{align}
There are other ways, using multifactorials, but the above is quite mechanical.

beautiful. thank you for this great explanation.

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\prod_{k=0}^{n}(2+3k)}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}(3+2k)}$.
I'm not sure I fully understood what you asked , but I hope this helped you .
